# boost beast WebSocket upgrade handshake failed

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-beast

Using the example code of boost::beast(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync-ssl/websocket_client_sync_ssl.cpp), I got:

*Error: WebSocket upgrade handshake failed*

To make sure the server is ok, i created a test using https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, and it server responses fine. The url is wss://api.fcoin.com/v2/ws, and my settings:

```
host=api.fcoin.com;
port=443;
target=/v2/ws;
```

Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beast example uses target of `/`, not `/v2/ws`. If you want to connect to that endpoint, you need to modify the example. Change:

```
ws.handshake(host, "/");
```

to

```
ws.handshake(host, "/v2/ws");
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks